# MySQL does not accept the value '5'

Tags: mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, eloquent, sql-update

I encountered a very strange behavior. I have a meta table with references.

Columns: id, ref_type, ref_id, ref_value, sort_order, created_at and updated_at

Working with Laravel, Eloquent.

I have a ref_type A, with ref_id-s 1 2 3 4 5 6

I am not able to save the reference 5 in any way.
t did not work through php and directly in phpMyAdmin neither

What I tried:

- Create model with Eloquent (no success)
- Insert record in phpMyAdmin (no success)
- Insert it with another ref_id (this works, with all the same data!) and change the ref_id afterwards (it says it is working, but after refresh the whole record is missing...)

There are no constraints on this table (only the id is PK, inc.), and also I dont get any error message, every time I try to insert, it runs without problems.

This occurred after I deleted this record with Eloquent through php code. But this code was not called again and the whole section was commented out as well.

I have really no clue what can cause this...

Comment: Can you please post your table schema and the specific error message?

Comment: I made a full database refresh and seed, because nothing else helped. Now the problem is solved, but the mystery remains... :)